# Save to .txt file a nested cell array in its original format: MATLAB

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, save, cell

In the algorithm that I am dealing with, the nested cells are randomly generated in MATLAB. Consider this nested cell:

`myCellArray ={2,2,1,1,{1,1,2,2,{1,2,{1,1,1,1,1}},2,2},{1,2,{1,2,2,2,2,2},2},{1,1},2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1};`

The corresponding **output** of the cell is:

`1×16 cell array
  Columns 1 through 13
    {[2]}    {[2]}    {[1]}    {[1]}    {1×7 cell}    {1×4 cell}    {1×2 cell}    {[2]}    {[2]}    {[2]}    {[2]}    {[1]}    {[1]}
  Columns 14 through 16
    {[1]}    {[1]}    {[1]}`

Since the cell is generated randomly through an algorithm, I do not have access to the   `myCellArray` in its **original** format (i.e., the way you write it as a command) written above. I must find a way to write the cell in its original command in a .txt file.

> Please let me know if you have any suggestion or comment. Thank you.

Comment: [This function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553646/2586922) I wrote some time ago seems to do exactly what you want. Note that arrays with more than 2 dimensions are not supported

Comment: Besides Luis' function, there are many similar ones on the [MATLAB File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?utf8=✓&term=cell2str).

Comment: Thanks, @LuisMendo. Your function is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad you found it helpful. Marking as duplicate then